# Send a Notification from Python to Firebase with Token

Tags: python, python-3.x, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I collected a token from the Firebase Javascript SDK and pass it back to my backend. I then use the below function to attempt to send a notification

I have authenticated properly and I am getting message ids when I print out the response but have never received a notification

I've tried to follow the documentation on firebase's site for [sending your first message](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/first-message) and I have not been able to figure out how to deliver a notification with the below content to myself despite having the token.

```py
def packet_signed_notification(token, signer):
    message = messaging.Message(
        token=token,
        webpush=messaging.WebpushConfig(
            notification=messaging.WebpushNotification(
                title='New Packet Signature!',
                body=signer + ' signed your packet! Congrats or I\'m Sorry',
                icon='https://exmaple.com/image/' + signer,
            ),
        )
    )
    response = messaging.send(message)
    print('Successfully sent message:', response)
```